# Qt Creator Project deletes Makefile in between builds

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I somehow seem to have jacked up a setting in my QtCreator project. I have a modified makefile in my projects build folder, and I am using that makefile to link in some external libraries, and point to other include files, etc.  It seems like in between builds, or during cleans, or something, Qt Is deleting that file, and I have to go back in and re-add the includes and such that I added manually. What am I doing wrong? How can I keep it from doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt mostly works with project files (*.pro) which it uses to generate Makefiles or Visual-Studio project files. Look for a file with the extension .pro in your project folder. You either have to lean how to handle project files or find ways to enter this information in QtCreator via the project tab.